# Optimal number and configuration of Git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, ide, branch

I have a Android app project which consists of:

- a standard Android project in ADT (the smartphone app)
- a PHP project in NetBeans (the API on the server)

So far, I have two separate Git repositories on Bitbucket, but I was wondering if this is the optimal solution, because for example I cannot use the same issue tracker for both of them.

I thought of 3 possible configurations, can you tell which is the correct approach?

1. Leave the repositories as they are, and use two separate issue trackers (or upgrade to one like Jira that allows multiple repositories)
2. Merge the two repositories, and make the two IDEs point at the same local folder (the cloned repository), opening each project in the appropriate IDE.
3. Merge the two repositories, and create two branches, one for Java (Android) and one for PHP. Checkout only the branch of interest in each IDE's workspace.

To me, **Solution 1** sounds quite clean, but only after purchasing a system like Jira (which I would avoid if possible). **Solution 2** sounds quite right, but it is a little annoying to point the IDEs outside their workspace. **Solution 3** is convenient, but it seems conceptually wrong.
What do you think? Is there maybe some other solution I didn't think of?

Comment: Solution 3 is completely wrong: what if you ever try to merge the two branches? Solution 1 seems the best one, whereas solution 2 is mostly a workaround.

Comment: @DaniloPiazzalunga: I also thought n°3 was wrong, but ideally I would have separate files in the branches. Theoretically, I would have one master branch, then two main branches for each part (one for Android, one for PHP), and various development branches for each main branch. I would first merge the dev branches in the main, and then the main into the master (if I would ever need do to so, as the two parts are in fact separate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/choosing-between-single-or-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository) on programmers.stackexchange,
I realized that **Solution 2** is clearly the best approach. Now the repository is structured like this:

```
|
+-- app/
|
+-- web/
|
+-- .gitignore
|
+-- README
```

The `app/` and `web/` folders contain the old repositories. I suggest reading the link above for a thorough explanation of the reasons why this approach is the best.